# Why do different users see a different number of questions in a tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

**DO NOT SAY CACHING**

I [asked about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221159/the-phone-tag-has-no-reason-to-exist-on-so) the [phone](/questions/tagged/phone) tag on SO. I saw 160 questions there (now 159):
[image]

At least 5 people say there are ten times as many according to the comments on my question.

Why? (Note that no tab is selected in that screenshot)

Comment: Maybe it is caching?

Comment: I think the real question is, *why* is no tab shown as selected in that screenshot?  Looks like a bug to me, unless something on your side (like a broken user script) is messing it up.  (Also, the text in the upper right corner is kind of misleading; it really ought to say e.g. "159 *frequent* questions tagged...")

Comment: Ps. Just [filed that last part as a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221211/fix-the-misleading-questions-tagged-message).

Answer (score 6):

Yours is defaulting to the `frequent` tab by the looks of it. there is `160` on there and overall there is `1,726`.

Guess there is a bug with the tab not highlighting? But that is the `frequent` tab. Lets see if I can find a way to also do that.

Comment: You are probably right, because if I switch to newest and then back to frequent I see the same numbers, but then why am I defaulted to frequent and why does the tab not appear selected?

Comment: @KateGregory How are you making your way to that tag? Searching, clicking a link etc? I will test to see if I can get it to default to it.

Comment: @KateGregory It's defaulting to that because the last time you were looking at a tag you had selected "frequent"?  It "remembers" your selection...

Comment: @Servy Sooooo basically some form of caching?

Comment: @KateGregory I can indeed confirm that, it remembers the tab you clicked last. Goob job Servy

Comment: @Ruddy clicking the link in a question - you can use the one in my question to try it. I think that should not remember your preferences, but if it does it should tell me that it does by highlighting the tab across the top

Comment: @KateGregory It does remember it but even on mine it does highlight the tab I am on. Even when going off the page and coming back to that tag by clicking the one in your question. How odd.

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Servy & Ruddy nice catch!