# Fix the misleading "# questions tagged" message

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, user-interface, tags-page

On a [tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags), the number of questions using the tag is shown prominently in the top right corner of the page:
[image: Screenshot of "newest" tab for the "tags" tag on Meta Stack Overflow, showing 4,211 tagged questions]

But sometimes, the number shown does not seem to match reality:
[image: Screenshot of "frequent" tab for the "tags" tag on Meta Stack Overflow, showing 1,342 tagged questions]

Of course, the more experienced users will have spotted the problem by now: in the second screenshot, I have the "frequent" tab selected, so it's showing me the number of *frequent* questions (whatever that actually means) for the tag, rather than the total number.

However, this is something you really only learn by bitter experience, after being confused by it enough times.  To new users, and some not-so-new users too, it's just plain confusing.

A big part of the problem is that the page very explicitly says "1,324 questions tagged [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)", even though, on the face of it, that statement is *just plain wrong!*  To make it correct, **it really should say something like "1,342 *frequent* questions tagged [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)" instead**.

Alternatively, we could just fix it so that the number shown in the corner is always the total number of questions using the tag(s), even if only a limited subset of them are actually shown.  Or we could show *both* numbers, as in "1,342 frequent questions out of 4,211 tagged [tags](/questions/tagged/tags)".

Of course, either way, the same fix should be applied to the "featured" and "unanswered" tabs too.

(Ps. See [Why do different users see a different number of questions in a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221167/why-do-different-users-see-a-different-number-of-questions-in-a-tag) for an example of the confusion this can cause even to experienced users.)

Comment: Pps. Sort of related issue: [Clicking on tags broken?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78989/clicking-on-tags-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the tabs that actually have a different number (frequent, featured and unanswered), I've pretty much just added the tab name to them.

All others reflect the question count.

With you in the next build (meta rev 2014.2.17.1960, main rev 2014.2.17.1375)